# How can I create an architecture independent snap?

Tags: packaging, snap

I've created a small snap package that contains no compiled architecture dependent code.  When I build the package it ends up named like `..._amd64.snap`, but there is no reason why the program within the snap couldn't run on any other architecture.

So is there a way I can build the snap so it can be installed on any architecture?

Comment: Have you tried installing it on a 32 bit installation? I think it's just a naming convention.

Comment: I just tried rebuilding the snap using `--target-arch=i386`, and then tried to install the resulting snap.  Installing the resulting snap fails with the error `Mount snap "hello-world" (unset) (snap "hello-world" supported architectures (i386) are incompatible with this system (amd64))`.  So the build architecture is being baked into the resulting snap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching around a bit, I found the solution in the [packaging for the `classic` snap](https://github.com/snapcore/classic-snap).  Edit the `snapcraft.yaml` file, and add the following at the top level:

```
architectures: [ all ]
```

Now when building the snap, the resulting file name will be `..._all.snap`, and the architecture in `prime/meta/snap.yaml` will also be set to `all` rather than the build system's architecture.

The resulting snap can be installed on any system regardless of its architecture.